# ListView no se visualiza bien al Deslizar

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo una clase abstracta genérica que hereda de `BaseAdapter` y la cual utilizo para cargar `ListView`(s) a partir de un `ArrayList` de objetos cualesquiera. La clase funciona bien y al ser abstracta me obliga a implementar el método `onEntrada` que es el que uso para cada objeto y la vista nueva que se rellenara, es decir el layout molde a rellenar.

Hasta aquí bien, el problema es que cuando deslizo el dedo sobre la tablet que tengo para las pruebas las letras de los TextViews si sobrescriben viéndose la cosa fatal, hasta que suelto y vuelve todo a su sitio.

Creía que el problema venía porque el ListView llama a la función getView continuamente y recarga todos los datos, por lo que probé con algo que encontré por aquí, crear una clase static ViewHolder con los Views iguales a los que necesito por fila e ir comprobando que no se ha rellenado, pero el resultado es el mismo. Se ve la cosa fatal. Ya no se si es problema de la versión de Android, del tamaño de la Tablet, del rendimiento(esta ultima me extraña, es una Samsung Galaxy de las ultimas y va muy bien). Si a alguien le ha pasado o mejor conoce la solución a ver si me podéis echar un cable.
Os dejo la clase que uso como Adpater.

```
public abstract class Lista_adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<?> entradas;
    private int R_layout_IdView;

    public Context getContexto() {
        return contexto;
    }

    private Context contexto;

    public Lista_adaptador(Context contexto, int R_layout_IdView, ArrayList<?> entradas) {
        super();
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.entradas = entradas;
        this.R_layout_IdView = R_layout_IdView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int posicion, View view, ViewGroup pariente)
    {View v = view;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);
            v = vi.inflate(R_layout_IdView, null);
        }
        else
        {

        }
        onEntrada(entradas.get(posicion), v);
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return entradas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int posicion) {
        return entradas.get(posicion);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int posicion) {
        return posicion;
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve cada una de las entradas con cada una de las vistas a la que debe de ser asociada
     *
     * @param entrada La entrada que será la asociada a la view. La entrada es del tipo del paquete/handler
     * @param view    View particular que contendrá los datos del paquete/handler
     */
    public abstract void onEntrada(Object entrada, View view);

}
```

Gracias Einer probe v = vi.inflate(R_layout_IdView,pariente, false); y sigue igual la cosa. Os adjunto una imagen de como se ve.

La clase es abstracta como digo la puede usar cualquier otra clase para cargar sus ListView, basta con tener un ArrayList de objetos cualesquiera e implementar el onEntrada() Ejemplo:

listaAgregados.setAdapter(new Lista_adaptador(this, R.layout.linea_nota, datosAgregados) {

```
        @Override
        public void onEntrada(Object entrada, View view) {
             //Aquí se rellenan los views de la view de entrada.
         }
```

Uno de los xml que uso para inflar las celdas de las listas es este:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_refLineaNota"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Referencia"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_nombreLineaNota"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Nombre de Linea de Nota"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_cantidadlineanota"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="Cantidad"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_tipounidadLineaNota"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:text="Kg" />
```

Comment: ¿podrías poner una imagen de lo que te está pasando para ver cómo se ve?

Comment: Intenta especificando el parent cuando inflas la vista:  `v = vi.inflate(R_layout_IdView, pariente, false);` y dinos que pasa.

Comment: Si esto se encuentra dentro de un Fragment, sería importante agregar como realizas la carga del fragment. @MiguelGijon

Comment: Jorgesys no se encuentra en un Fragment, sino en varios Activity. Uso una versión antigua de SDK y no me deja usar Fragment. Arriba he puesto una llamada al setAdapter.

Comment: puede que el error venga de usas android:layout_weight

Answer (score 0):

El error parece bastante raro, y sin el código para poder hacer debug tendre que hacer un par se suposiciones. Lo primero es que me parece un poco rara la forma como implementas el el adapter, dejando que una clase externa implemente el metodo onEntrada y que sea esta ultima la que infle la lista. Tal vez sea debido a esto que se genera ese efecto tan raro, ya que mientras el adapter controla el scroll de la lista, es otra activity quien esta inflando a medida que se hace el scroll los elementos de la lista. Te recomiende que cambies la forma en que implementas el adapter a una forma mas estandar. No entiendo muy bien el funcionamiento de onEntrada, pero al no ver que modifiques el view en "getView()" supondre que lo haces en "onEntrada()
"

Comment: La forma de implementar el Adpater es para poder reutilizar el código con más ListView y solamente especificar en onEntrada los Views especificos para cada ListView concreto. Por ello la función onEntrada es abstracta y recibiendo el arrayList de objetos con un Casteo los transformo en el que necesite y leyendo dichos datos por cada entrada puedo rellenar los Views que quiero.

Comment: Hay otras formas de hacer lo que planteas, puedes usar tipos genericos e interfaces para controlar los eventos, o migrar a kotlin y usar funciones lambda. Estoy bastante seguro que el problema se da al cambiar el el view desde otra parte y no desde el adapter. Intenta hacer una prueba, cambia la logica de onEntrada() y solo infla la vista en getView() para ver si eso es lo que genera el error, tabmien seria bueno que me compartieras el codigo que tienes en la implementacion de onEntrada()

Comment: Jhon Fredy Trujillo Ortega antes de nada darte las gracias por la atención. Revisando lo que me comentas y obviando lo de krotlin, que al nivel que llevo ya el proyecto ya es imposible, me dices que lo que hace la función onEntrada() lo haga desde getView(), eso ya se hace, ya que getView es el encargado de inflar, ¿el que infla? pues un layout con id generico que se lo especifico yo al crear el adaptador y cuando acaba de inflar el layout llama a la función onEntrada que es donde se le asigna el setText a los textos. Eso es lo mismo que si se hiciera dentro de getview. No creo que sea eso.

Comment: No se si podría ser un fallo de la tablet samsung al visualizar o algo no se. Es como si no borrara el texto de los TextViews que se estan arrastrando hasta que no suelte el dedo.

Comment: Yo considero que no es lo mismo, debido a que el metodo onEntrada() es implementado de manera externa. Estoy bastante seguro que no es la tablet, de ser asi, me hubiera encontrado en algun momento con este tipo de errores ya que es una simple lista. Otra cosa, me podiras mostar el xml que usar para inflar las celdas de la lista?